# SQL Server Capture Execution Plan 

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I want to capture execution plan only for long running query (5 minutes) for this I have used extended event but the plan_handle which is returned by extended events does not produce an execution plan when I pass this plan_handle to sys.dm_exec_query_plan. But for the same statement I am getting execution plan when I use sys.dm_exec_query_stats.

Is it possible to get execution plan only for long running query using server side trace

My motto is to capture execution plan for long running queries & save this plan in target for later analysis. For this purpose I can't go with dmv's please

Comment: You can use [Extended Events with SQL 2012 or later](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan/33657996#33657996)

Answer (score 0):

This will be possible in the next version (SQL Server 2012). [See related connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/648351/extended-events-action-to-collect-actual-execution-plan).